# User login in Azure hosted webapp

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-entra-id, identity-provider

How can I implement user authentication with a username and password in the Azure Cloud while utilizing Microsoft managed services, specifically avoiding the use of a client-managed database for user credentials? The users will not be Microsoft account holders.

Tried using EntraID/Azure AD, but could not find the option to use username and password combo for non Microsoft users.

Comment: Is possible to use third-party identity provider like Auth0 or Okta. It can be integrated either with Azure AD or with Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use B2C with another [IDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider).

But B2C isn't for integrating with SaaS apps e.g. O365.

What managed services do you want to use?